# access Tinymce instance from iframe parent

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I wonder if it possible to access Tinymce that exists inside Iframe (file) from the parent HTML:

```
<html>....
    <script>
        <!-- HERE I WANT TO ACCESS THE TINYMCE INSIDE tinymce.html-->
    </script>

    <body>
        <iframe src="tinymce.html" align="middle" width="0" height="0" name="myFrame" id="myFrame"></iframe>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dom needs to be created first. After that you may access the iframe content. See my code:

```
<html>....
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          console.log('body: ', $('iframe').first().contents().find('body'));
        });
    </script>

    <body>
        <iframe src="tinymce.html" align="middle" name="myFrame" id="myFrame"></iframe>
    </body>

</html>
```